MariaDB Spider Tuning
if I have a Spider database which has only Spider tables, what are important configuration keys for tuning the Spider ? For example, i heard about Spider and how it works with MEMORY table so should i increase key_buffer_size in a Spider-only MariaDB ? What about other spider_ parameters ? What are the important spider_ variables ? it has over 123 variables !!! My server has 32-Core CPU and 256 GB of RAM.

What is Spider in your case? Storage engine? Some third-party software? else?

@Akina my server has spider tables (engine).
